# How do I measure query performance on Informix?

Tags: sql, performance, profiling, informix

I have some performance issues with Informix queries. How can I profile these queries to narrow down the source of the problem?

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0409fan/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0409fan/):-

> The most comprehensive tool that Informix provides for collecting
>   detailed SQL query plans and execution statistics is the SET EXPLAIN
>   utility. This utility will generate a file called sqexplain.out, and
>   records in detail every step of the query execution. In addition it
>   provides the estimated costs of the query and estimates the query
>   results. By examining the SET EXPLAIN output file, you can determine
>   if steps can be taken to improve the performance of the query. The
>   following example shows the set explain output for a pretty complex
>   query:

```
SELECT --+AVOID_FULL(omchn)+AVOID_FULL(daphn)
                omchn.omc_hn_uanc,
                nvl(daphn.gtt_version,"0000000000000000000"),
                nvl(idachn.egt4_version,"0000000000000000000"),
                nvl(ihlrhn.hlr_timestamp,"00000000000000"),
                vsgw_hn.hn_igw_uanc,
                nvl(vsgw_hn.hn_igw_version, "00000000000000")
           FROM omchn, daphn, idachn, ihlrhn, vsgw_hn
          WHERE daphn.dap_hn_inst  = omchn.omc_hn_inst
            AND idachn.idac_hn_inst = omchn.omc_hn_inst
            AND ihlrhn.hlr_hn_inst = omchn.omc_hn_inst
            AND vsgw_hn.vsgw_hn_inst = omchn.omc_hn_inst

DIRECTIVES FOLLOWED:
AVOID_FULL ( omchn )
AVOID_FULL ( daphn )
DIRECTIVES NOT FOLLOWED:

Estimated Cost: 8
Estimated # of Rows Returned: 1

  1) root.idachn: SEQUENTIAL SCAN

  2) root.daphn: INDEX PATH

    (1) Index Keys: dap_hn_inst   (Serial, fragments: ALL)
        Lower Index Filter: root.daphn.dap_hn_inst = root.idachn.idac_hn_inst
NESTED LOOP JOIN

  3) root.vsgw_hn: SEQUENTIAL SCAN
NESTED LOOP JOIN

  4) root.omchn: INDEX PATH

                Filters: root.vsgw_hn.vsgw_hn_inst = root.omchn.omc_hn_inst
            (1) Index Keys: omc_hn_inst   (Serial, fragments: ALL)
      Lower Index Filter: root.idachn.idac_hn_inst = oot.omchn.omc_hn_inst
NESTED LOOP JOIN

     5) root.ihlrhn: INDEX PATH

            (1) Index Keys: hlr_hn_inst   (Serial, fragments: ALL)
      Lower Index Filter: root.ihlrhn.hlr_hn_inst = root.omchn.omc_hn_inst
NESTED LOOP JOIN
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select  der.session_id,
der.blocking_session_id, 
der.wait_type, 
der.wait_time,
der.start_time, 
DATEDIFF(second,der.start_time,GETDATE())/60.0 AS executeTime_Minutes,
percent_complete,
der.status as requestStatus, 
des.login_name, 
cast(db_name(der.database_id) as varchar(30)) as databaseName,
 des.program_name,
 der.command as commandType,
der.percent_complete,
case des.transaction_isolation_level
 when 0 then 'Unspecified' when 1 then 'ReadUncomitted'
 when 2 then 'ReadCommitted' when 3 then 'Repeatable'
 when 4 then 'Serializable' when 5 then 'Snapshot'
 end as transaction_isolation_level,
char(13) + char(10) + Current Command + char(13) + char(10) + 
case when der.statement_end_offset = -1 then
```

--see objectText-- 
      else SUBSTRING(execText.textder.statement_start_offset/2,                           (der.statement_end_offset - der.statement_start_offset)/2) 
     end + char(13) + char(10) + '------Full Object------------' AS      currentExecutingCommand,
     execText.text as objectText
    from sys.dm_exec_sessions des 
--returns information about each user and internal  system session on a SQL Server instance including session settings, security, and cumulative CPU, memory, and I/O usage
    join sys.dm_exec_requests as der 
--The sys.dm_exec_requests DMV shows us what is currently running
    on der.session_id = des.session_id
--on the SQL Server instance, its impact on memory, CPU, disk, and cache.
    outer apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(der.sql_handle) as execText
    where --des.session_id <> @@spid and 
     des.session_id > 40;

Comment: Sorry to not clarify but this would be active queries and processes. I assumed one tool would be a statistical output to compare different versions.